# Is there any advantage to staying on very old linux kernels?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, vulnerability

When I visit https://www.kernel.org/ I see a variety of kernel versions. At the time of writing there is one mainline, two stables, and a whopping six longterms. The oldest is 4.9. Is there a reason to stay on such an old kernel? Don't outdated kernels have more vulnerabilities?

Comment: Let's say $HARDWARE_VENDOR only provides support for the oldest kernel they can get away with. If you absolutely *have* to use their product for some reason, then what can you do? "Don't outdated kernels have more vulnerabilities?" .... more *discovered* vulnerabilities, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stability. Newer kernels have tens of thousands of changed lines of code which often means new regressions and behavioral changes. When you have a device which needs to run 24x7, you couldn't care less about shiny new kernels.
2. Drivers. New kernels may not necessarily support your HW properly due to changes in drivers or related subsystems. Testing new kernels often means a good amount of downtime. Sometimes testing is not even possible since you don't have enough spare systems to dedicate to testing.
3. Kernel APIs. Kernel developers keep [breaking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/stable-api-nonsense.rst) kernel API/ABI all the time and there are companies which run out-of-tree drivers which sometimes don't even have source code available or it's available but there are no people to port it to new kernels. Porting also requires extensive debugging and results in a downtime.

Very little in the world revolves around new and shiny. Literally hundreds of thousands of system must run 24x7 where stability is paramount.

Comment: +1 Cannot agree more ! : Perhaps could you add to your answer with regards to OP's fears that all "*old kernels*" displayed on the kernel.org page are LTS, meaning that known stability & security issues are supposed to be addressed in the version/release offered to download.